Request for source code files related to the APSL-2.0 license used in the Google Maps SDK for iOS
I am using the Google Maps SDK for iOS.
I have added the license statement in accordance with the attribution requirements (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/overview#attribution_requirements).
Upon reviewing the added license statement, I confirmed that APSL-2.0 is being used.
APSL-2.0 requires source code disclosure.
In order for me to use Google Maps SDK for iOS, I need the source code for APSL-2.0 included in Google Maps SDK for iOS.
In compliance with the license obligations, I would like to request the following files:

src/client/mac/handler/breakpad_nlist_64.cc
src/third_party/mac_headers/architecture/byte_order.h
src/third_party/mac_headers/mach-o/arch.h
src/third_party/mac_headers/mach-o/fat.h
src/third_party/mac_headers/mach-o/loader.h
src/third_party/mac_headers/mach-o/nlist.h

Please let me know how I can receive the above files, and kindly send them to me.
(The above file list is the file that is specified as APSL-2.0 in the Notice.
If there are other files that include a license that requires source code disclosure, please share the source for those files as well.)

This isn't the place to request those files.

While I understand that you're trying to request source code files related to the APSL-2.0 license, Stack Overflow is focused on programming and technical questions. Requests for files or legal/licensing matters are outside the scope of this site.
I recommend reaching out to the Google Maps SDK support team or checking their documentation for guidance on obtaining these files.

fyi - customer support questions are off-topic here - check out Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow? as well as Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?
